# Javascript and Cross Origin

Tags: javascript, php, json

i've been working on a lookup using a third party API, so someone completes a form, submits it, this then looks up the record at the third party and returns an array.

I've got it working on 2 seperate pages but i'd like to roll it into one page and remove the need for a refresh, I looked at converting the code and using and xhr request to get the data but the thrid party have said it wont work because they don't support Cross Origin data/lookups.

I know tha PHP and Javascript are totally different and that PHP is executed server side but is there a way to use OnClick on the button to pass the form data using php get the results then pass that to javascript?

any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

so in short i wanted to be able to condense these 2 pages into one so they enter the lookup details, click submit, it then runs the lookup from page 2 and fills in the second form.

Code is as followS:
page 1:

```
<?php
//login and get authtoken
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://thirdpartyurl.com",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n\"grant_type\" : \"client_credentials\",\r\n\"client_id\" : \"NEWTOCODE\",\r\n\"client_secret\": \"PASSHERE\"\r\n}\r\n",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "authorization: Bearer da97e45a4690fb34fe409571a40ef325412d576b",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",

  ),
));

//  $response = curl_exec($curl);


curl_close($curl);


?>

<div id="content" class="full-width" style="padding-left: 100px;">
<p>For demo purposes only </p>


       <form method="post" action="page2.php"> 
  <label for="Name">Name</label>  <input type="text" name="Name" value=""> <br/>
  <label for="email">Email</label>  <input type="text" name="Email" value=""> <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

    </div>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
$NAME1= $_POST["name"];
$Email= $_POST["email"];
$curl = curl_init();
// complete lookup using posted data
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://thirdpartyurl.com/lookup",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n   \"NAME\": \"$NAME1\",\r\n   \"EMAIL\":\"$EMAIL1\"\r\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/thirdpartyurl.com.v2+json",
    "authorization: Bearer 6323arad0",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/thirdpartyurl.com.v2+json",

  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);


$userData = json_decode($response, TRUE);


?>
<form>
 <label for="Name">Name</label>  <input type="text" name="Name" value=""> <br/>
  <label for="Email">Mileage</label>  <input type="text" name="Email" value=""> <br/>
 <label for="add1">address1</label>  <input type="text" name="add1" value=""> <br/>
 <label for="add2">address2</label>  <input type="text" name="add2" value=""> <br/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// pass PHP array to JavaScript array
var userDetails = <?php echo $response ?>;



var name = userDetails['user']['personal']['name'];
var email= userDetails['user']['personal']['email'];
var add1= userDetails['add1'];
var add2 = userDetails['add2'];


//populate new form
document.getElementsByName("Name")[0].value = name;
document.getElementsByName("Email")[0].value = email;
document.getElementsByName("add1")[0].value = add1;
document.getElementsByName("add2")[0].value = add2;
</script>
```

Comment: you can use curl in php for that.

Comment: @jcubic, thanks it's using curl in php to get the data when i use 2 pages but wasnt sure how i then condensed it down to one page..

Comment: There is two ways first one is to post form data by CURL and 2nd one is jsonp method hopefully it's support the cross domain.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: ill update the question with the code now!

Comment: You don't use $response on first page anywhere, why you need that first curl?

Comment: @jcubic sorry that was from testing i left it in by mistake

Comment: has anyone got any tips or adivce, i'm still struggling with this?